# Scapy speed up sniff performance

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, filter, scapy

I have a python script using the scapy 2.4.3 sniff() fuction, running in a thread:

`sniff(iface=self.iface, store=0, filter="(ip and not src net %s) and (udp dst port %s)" % (self.ip_src, str(self.dport)), prn=self.handle_someip_packet)`

It came to my attention that the execution of this sniffing thread is take too much time.

I would like to set the conf.layers.filter([UDP]), but I get the error:
AttributeError: 'LayersList' object has no attribute 'filter'

What am I doing wrong?

Any other ideas to speed the scapy sniffing?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using an older version of scapy without realizing. Try using 2.4.4rc2 (`pip3 install scapy --pre`)

You can check the version using `scapy.__version__`